# Magento 1: how to properly redirect from an admin controller observer?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, redirect, magento-1, admin-controller

Ok, so I want to do some validations when submitting the mass update product attributes.

I've setup an observer like this:

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_action_attribute_save>
            <observers>
                <fxcons_controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_action_attribute_save>
                    <class>fxcons/observer</class>
                    <method>validateConsolidatedAttributesOnSave</method>
                </fxcons_controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_action_attribute_save>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_action_attribute_save>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

Then in my observer I do the following:

```
public function validateConsolidatedAttributesOnSave(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    // Get the controller action
    $controllerAction = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();

    if (several checks here)
    {
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('fxcons')->__('Fail'));
        Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($controllerAction->getUrl('*/sales_order/'));
        Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
    }
}
```

So the fail message is properly getting displayed but I never get redirected to the sales order grid and I also get the success "X products have been updated" message. On top of that the controller still updates the product and I don't want it to.

I have tried setting the "return_url" on the request param as well but didn't work.

Comment: try adding `exit;` after `Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are not stopping the current request. You need the following code too:

```
    /** @var $controller Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action */
    $controller = $observer->getData('controller_action');
    $controller->setFlag(
         $controller->getRequest()->getActionName(),
         Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH,
         true
     );
```

Comment: Using Observer how to get selected admin user and use a condition like If selected admin user logged in,  the dashboard Choose Store View: is selected store.